# Rails 4 scope model/controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, view, controller, scope

In my  model I've defined:

```
scope :active, -> { where(active: 'true') }
```

And my controller

```
def index
    if logged_in? 
     @objects = Objects.all
    else 
    @objects = Objects.active
    end 
  end
```

In my index view, when logged_in? is true, I get all records as expected, but otherwise, I get nothing (I know at least one record is active).

Have I written my scope incorrectly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be

```
scope :active, -> { where(active: true) }
```

Note: `true` is not enclosed in quotes